# ADO.NET DBConcurrencyException - Trying to update an already deleted row

Tags: c#, concurrency, ado.net, sqlcommandbuilder

Why is ADO.NET throwng a **DBConccurencyException**, when I try to update a row that is already deleted by another process, instead of just ignoring the deleted row?

Is there any available option in ADO.NET to ignore this fact?

I am using **SQLCommandBuilder** with **ConflictOption** set to **ConflictOption.OverwriteChanges**.

Comment: This is by design. Why not just handle the exception and carry on gracefully?

Comment: Do you have a source for your assumption :) ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163924.aspx take a look at the code in Figure 3...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DataViewRowState enumeration to select only the modified rows.

```
var rowsToUpdate =
            dataTable.Select(null, null, DataViewRowState.ModifiedOriginal);
```

Comment: how does this work? Is ADO.NET querying the row immediately before updating it?

Comment: ado.net checks the state before updating. If the row has been deleted it can't access it any longer